# Docker build with -f option cannot find Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have tried a lot of combinations with the docker -f option but I have never got it to work

I can do this:

```
docker build -t foo/bar .
```

But I cannot do this:

```
docker build -t foo/bar -f Dockerfile .
```

or this:

```
docker build -t foo/bar -f ./Dockerfile .
```

This gives me the following error:

```
unable to prepare context: The Dockerfile (c:\path\Dockerfile) must be within the build context (.)
```

I am using docker through the default vm on Windows 7. Docker version is 1.8.1, build d12ea79

I cannot see the difference. It could be very nice to have different Dockerfiles for different tasks on a project, but without the -f option that is really not possible.

Answer (score 7):

Well, as the error message is suggesting, your `Dockerfile` is not within the `context`,  which is the current directory (`.`) in your case.

**The docker file, specified with `-f`, must always be within the *context* directory specified as an argument**.

So, normally this should work fine:

```
docker build -f /path/to/context/dir/Dockerfile /path/to/context/dir
```

And this too:

```
cd /some/dir
docker build -f /some/dir/customDir/Custom-Dockerfile-name .
```

While, this would fail:

```
docker build -f /path/to/diff/dir/Dockerfile /path/to/context/dir
```

From the [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/):

```
docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
```

> The docker build command builds Docker images from a Dockerfile and a “context”. A build’s context is the set of files located in the specified PATH or URL

And:

> By default the docker build command will look for a Dockerfile at the root of the build context. The -f, --file, option lets you specify the path to an alternative file to use instead. This is useful in cases where the same set of files are used for multiple builds. The path must be to a file within the build context. If a relative path is specified then it is interpreted as relative to the root of the context.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of how I used the docker build to avoid this error

docker build -f my.dockerfile **./**

Note the trailing forward slash

Comment: Not sure why that would make a difference in this case

Comment: If I didn't specify the trailing forward slash it would not work. Somehow . was invalid as the context. I experienced this running Docker natively on Linux and OSX.

Comment: Maybe it worked for you, but seems like a weird edge case

Comment: Subsequently I have never needed the trailing slash again .. wierd

Answer (score 2):

Coming in a little bit late here but I ran into this issue yesterday. Basically, when using the dot (`.`) you are setting up your current directory as the working directory - if you are using the `-f` flag then most likely that's not right. So you need to do the following:

```
docker build -f /path/to/Dockerfile /path/to/
```

Notice the `/path/to/` replacing the `.`. This places the docker script in the right context. You can use any other flag (like `-t`) if needed.

```
docker build -t foo/bar -f /path/to/Dockerfile /path/to/
```

This is working for me like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this issue, and it turns out that it was caused by my dockerfile being on a disk mounted as a folder in NTFS. Once I moved it to a regular folder, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If your `Dockerfile` is not in the project root (current directory), show it after the `-f`.

Here is an example I used:

```
docker build -t test_service -f deployment/dev/Dockerfile .
```

Answer (score -1):

if you do

```
docker build --help
```

you will notice, among other things

```
-f, --file=                     Name of the Dockerfile (Default is 'PATH/Dockerfile')
```

you can do either

```
docker build -t mytag .
```

or

```
docker build -t mytag -f another_dockerfile
```

but you can't use `.` and the `-f` together.

It is `.`, or the Dockerfile with `-f`, not both

Comment: docker: "build" requires 1 argument.
See 'c:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build a new image from the source code at PATH

Comment: That is the answer when build is run without a PATH

Comment: if your dockerfile is in your current directory, you just run `docker build .`

Comment: can you post tour `docker version` ? Maybe related to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14339

Comment: Docker version 1.8.1, build d12ea79